# How to give permission to access denied on dynamic page click in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to write the access denied code in PHP on the page to check if the user comes directly to my page without the "book_id" button clicked.

If he comes to my page from the previous page using Check Below Line of code otherwise access denied.

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="book_detail.php?book_id=<?=$book_id['id'];?>" style="width:120px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Add To Cart</a>
```

**Supposed:**

```
book_id = 1  // (This is the real problem- its dynamic, could be any number 1,2,3,4,5,......)
User id = 5
```

I have a dynamic code in php to new page like:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="book_detail.php?book_id=<?=$book_id['id'];?>" style="width:120px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Add To Cart</a>
```

**Now I want to know:**

```
book_detail.php?book_id=1; //This will work if user come from button click
book_detail.php?book_id=2; // This will also work if user come from button click
```

But This will access denied because the user directly created the URL like:

```
book_detail.php?book_id=5 // or any other number/id which are in the database;
```

I tried: But not working as I am failed to implement this. Not know how to implement this $url != 'what to pass here as I have dynamic URL';

```
$url != 'your-url-which-you-do-not-what-direct access';

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == $url) {
    header('Location: otherurl.php'); //redirect to some other page
    exit();
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be welcome.

Thank You.

Comment: The referrer is highly unreliable - always has been, and these days you should expect even more privacy extensions etc. to either manipulate it, or filter it out completely. If anything, this should be done via the session - store the info, that the user _was_ on whatever page you need/want them to visit first, in there, and then check for it in the other script to decide whether to grant access or not.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are trying to use might not work out for you. Try this instead. Before you render each button on a page assign it a unique id and store the id somewhere, probably in an array in session.

When the page `book_detail.php?book_id=5` loads get the value of book_id, if it's present check if the value exists in the array of ids you created earlier and stored in session, If it does render ur page if it does not exist or book_id is not present display permission denied.

However keep in mind that:
 1. The ids would have to be changed each time the page is refreshed.
 2. Someone can still inspect ur page copy the id for the button and run in the browser although it really won't make any sense for them to do that especially since the id would expire after first use.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But unfortunately I am not able to implement this as I don't understand completely what you are suggesting me to do. Kindly share your thoughts again in example. Than You.